# Listview postion not working properly

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have list view. I want to change color of clicked row. But only 0,1 and 2 indexes are correctly colored others are not working properly likewise if i clicked on 4th row the 5th one row color changes and sometimes if i clicked on 7th row then none of row is colored. Please Help

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,final int position, long id) {

            for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if(position == i ){
                    lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }else{
                    lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            }



  public abstract class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    Context context;      
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countryList;        
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mStringFilterList;
    LayoutInflater inflter;
    public ImageView img2,img3;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    SeekBar songProgressBar;
    SelfUpdatingSeekbar self;
    public boolean isStarted = true;
    public static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
    public static final int STEP_VALUE = 4000;
    public final Handler handler = new Handler();


    public final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updatePosition();
        }
    };

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countryList) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.countryList = countryList;
        mStringFilterList =  countryList;

        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countryList.size();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countryList) {
        this.countryList = countryList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_itemss, null);

        view.setTag(position);

        String hello = String.valueOf(countryList.get(position));
        String s = hello;
        int s1 = s.lastIndexOf("=");
        int s2 = s.lastIndexOf("}");

         strSub = s.substring(s1+1,s2/*s.lastIndexOf("=")*/);

        Log.d("Hello",hello);
        String henno1 = String.valueOf(hello.length());
        Log.d("hellya",strSub);

        TextView country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        country.setText(strSub);

         uniqueItemIdCount = countryList.size();

        Log.d("PrintIdss", String.valueOf(uniqueItemIdCount));

        ImageView twitt = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.button5);

        twitt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(context)
                        .text(strSub);

                builder.show();
            }
        });

        ImageView fb = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.button6);

        fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle(strSub)
                        .setContentDescription(
                                "Top Hollywood Songs")
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.moremovies.com/"))
                        .build();

                shareDialog.show(linkContent);
            }
        });




        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);


        img2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.button3);


        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                int songIndex = position;



                String hellos = String.valueOf(countryList.get(songIndex));
                int s1 = hellos.lastIndexOf("=");
                int s2 = hellos.lastIndexOf("}");

              String  strSubs = hellos.substring(s1+1,s2/*s.lastIndexOf("=")*/);
                selelctedFile.setText(strSubs);

                currentSongIndex=songIndex;

                playSong(currentSongIndex);


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: use if(position == (i +1)){

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40821343/6756514

Comment: no luck !!!! its not coloring the first row !!! and if i click on second row the third will colored!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage the position and the background of yourself because in your adapter as you are reusing the cell. Kindly check your adapter you will get it.

And to achieve what you want. You have to update your adapter and implement the click listener in the Adapter view.

Comment: right said bro.. I am basically using the button in my row which is in adapter i want to convert that button into different image on button click!!! can you please help me with the code. I updated my code now!!!

Comment: Code Updated!!! basically i have a list of songs in in which every row has play button!! i want to convert particulat button into pause button!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to subtract the position of your listview:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if(position - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() == i ){ //<-Here
        lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }else{
        lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start with play buttons and on click change to pause the one clicked and all others back to play then inside your adapter where you initialize the play/pause button do :

```
playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {               
             lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,final int position, long id) {
                     for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
                          Button PlayPause = v.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_button)
                          ButtonPlayPause.setImageResource("play resource")
                     }
                     playPause.setImageResource("pause resource")
                  }          
             }
        }
    });
```

Code may have some syntax errors but you get the idea.

Comment: lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,final int position, long id) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                            }
                            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);
                        }    });      This is my code but no t working on click!!! on button it changes sometimes different row image !!!

Comment: Try :  img2 is inside every child of lv which is View v. So do Button PlayPause = v.findViewById("id of img2") and then img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the two background options, because the adapter will reuse your layout.

So you need to keep track of the selected items (not layouts), as i see you are using a HashMap to populate your adapter so, create a List with the selected positions and when you are populating your adapter do something like :

```
 //Globals Variables
 List<int> SelectedList = new ArrayList<>();

 //On select event
 SelectedList.add(position);

 //On deselect event
 SelectedList.remove(position);


 //On get view
if(SelectedList.contains(position){

     // Background selected
}else{
   // Explicit set the background to the default
}
```

Comment: countryList.add(String.valueOf(position));  // I choose this line in my Arraylist<String> is it right? if yes then its not working :/